# How to use Jasny Fileupload in update/edit operation? This is letting field in blank when user don't change image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Jasny Fileupload](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) to add and update some images, everything works fine when user add a new image, but when user will update images and don't change the image, the image reference is sent in blank.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong or how to preserve the image name when user don't change anything?

Tks

Below it follows:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="">Foto 1-1 (432x254px):</label>
  <div class="controls">
  <div class="fileupload fileupload-exists" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"><img src="http://localhost/Figoli-Ravecca/backoffice/user_data/<?php echo mysql_result($result,0,"f_1_1_c"); ?>" /></div>
  <div>      
  <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file"  name="files[2]" /></span>
  <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is answered in the article ['Jasny Bootstrap – File upload with existing file'](http://www.jasny.net/articles/jasny-bootstrap-file-upload-with-existing-file/) in detail.

Comment: Your Article Not Work For me. please check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/Y7hGh/

Comment: That article has been written for Bootstrap/Jasny Bootstrap 2. You need to update the classes to reflect version 3. http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/Y7hGh/1/

Comment: This Worked Now But I have Big Problem. i work with php. when preview image is empty i need to show only no+image and select bottun not empty div and change / remove bottun: please check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/Y7hGh/2/

Comment: Post it as a new question please.

Comment: New Q :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570128/jasny-upload-image-preview-plugin-when-existing-image-is-empty