# jasny upload image preview plugin when existing image is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with jasny upload image preview plugin for bootstrap 3 But this does not work when preview image is empty. I need to show only `no+image` and `select image` button not `empty div` and `change / remove` button.

HTML:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-exists" data-provides="fileinput" data-name="myimage">
    <input type="hidden" name="myimage" value="1" />
    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;">

    </div>
    <div> <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
        <input type="file" />
        </span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this Problem?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/Y7hGh/2/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correclty your issue, I think this is because you used `fileupload-exists` instead of `fileinput-exists`. So the mark-up for the preview container should be like this:

```
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" 
     style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change: fileinput-exists in your top line of code to fileinput-new in case of no preview image is provided.

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-exists" data-provides="fileinput" data-name="myimage">
```

To:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput" data-name="myimage">
```